# WordPress cms and blog with same site, how to code blog's index page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am coding up a cms site which also has a blog section by using wordpress.

the website previous had a blog section at /blog, which powered by wordpress, and a bunch of static pages. now they want to convert entire site to wordpress.

basically what i did is making a handful of "page"s , and set the website's index page as one of these static "page". apparently the blog section need to be part of this wordpress installation.

now i am wondering how do i render the index page of the blog as index.php has been taken for the "cms" part?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear - but there are two options for "home" page and "blog" page. Home page you have set, you can then set another page as the blog index.

Of course you will need a page template for that page so that it retrieves the latest blog entries.